# Powershell cmdlet is not recognized despite having the correct module installed

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to run a powerhsell script (my_script). The script is stored in `this_folder` on the desktop. I am executing the command at the the correct path by using `C:\Users\me\desktop\this_folder> .\my_script`. When I try to do this I get the error

`The term 'Add-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again`

I know that the `Add-AzureRmAccount` is a part of the `AzureRM.Profile` module. When I got to the modules folder, I see that `AzureRM.Profile` is listed. To get these modules, I ran `Install-Module -name AzureRM` and `Import-module AzureRM`.

Any ideas what might be going on?

---Update---
When I ran `Get-Module` commands I saw that only that AzureRM module was listed. I thne tried to run `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Profile` and got the error:

```
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
```

Since I see the `AzureRM.Profile` folder with a `nupkg` at one of the paths listed by `$env:PSModulePath` I thought I could just run `Import-Module -Name AzureRM.Profile` and I get the error

```
import-module : The specified module 'AzureRM.Profile' was not 
loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Additional troubleshooting: `Get-Module`, `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, `Get-Command Add-AzureRmAccount`

Comment: another diagnostic step ... `($env:PSModulePath).Split(';')`. at least one of those will very per account - the 1st on my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you've installed and imported the AzureRM module, but have you connected the Azure account with the `Connect-AzureRmAccount` cmdlet?
I know a number of other modules does not expose all of the available cmdlets until there is an active connection to an account/subscription.

Be aware that scripts can ignore the context in which they are run so you might need to add the following to the start of the script:

```
Import-Module AzureRM
Connect-AzureRmAccount
```

Rather than running them manually in the console and then running the script.

You might want also want to look at using the Az module instead as the AzureRM module is being retired, and will only get bug-fixes till the end of December 2020: [Introducing the new Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.4.0)

Comment: I added a few additional comments to my post. It may provide some additional insight at the issues I am facing. I will also try what you have mentioned.

Comment: I tried adding the above to my script. I get Connect-AzureRMAccount is not the name of a cmdlet error

Comment: What happens if you start a powershell session and run Import-Module Azure-RM and Connect-AzureRmAccount after one another?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/connect-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: So when I try to run the import command I get the error ```Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM.Profile' with version '5.8.2' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.``` But it is listing the wrong path. Can I manually tell it what path to look for modules in?

Comment: Are you running PS as administrator? 

I've not used the AzureRM module myself, but it may need admin-rights.

It is possible to specify the path for Import-Module: `Import-Module -Name c:\ps-test\modules\test -Verbose`

Comment: Yes I am using PS as admin. Let me try defining the path

Comment: Adding the path did not help. AzureRM is showing when I list available modules. When I try to run Connect-AzureRMAccount it says it is not a cmdlet